Tried to unlock Sony Xperia 5 III bootloader - now: "FAILED (Write to device failed (no link))"
As per title, I am trying to unlock the bootloader on my Sony Xperia 5 III. I have the global variant (XQ-BQ52) and confirmed it is unlockable. I am on W10 Ryzen based desktop system. I tried to follow Sony's "How to unlock bootloader", I got code as per Sony's "Unlock your device". I would like to say I have unlocked bootloaders and installed custom ROMS before - somehow this was quite different.
In first try, I didn't realise I was in "fastbootd". I rebooted to "fastboot" and had to reinstall the drivers. This time, I had to browse for a driver with the Window's choose-a-driver-GUI instead of choosing the folder downloaded with Google USB drivers - this was a bit weird to me.
Nonetheless, it seemed it worked since I got proper respond to fastboot devices.
So, for the unlocking part; admittedly, I was confused regarding the command
fastboot oem unlock 0x stating on Sony's guide. I might be stupid, but did not understand where to put in the code. First, I did the exact command and of course got nothing. Then I replaced 0x with my code, and then Terminal just hang forever. After a few minutes, I decided to kill the command with CTRL + C. I might have screwed up big time.
Now, when for instance trying fastboot reboot I get
Rebooting                                          FAILED (Write to device failed (no link))
fastboot: error: Command failed

I can still "ping" my device and get proper response with fastboot devices, but I must say I am kind of scared to proceed from here. Found this link but I am unsure whether this applies to my case.
I made a post on XDA's forums as well, and now it seems I indeed messed up with the unlock code input. But still, don't know if I made things worse with killing the command or perhaps even installing wrong drivers.
My phone is still in fastboot mode (with blue LED), and I am afraid to disconnect and potentially mess even more up.
I hope I provided enough details. THANKS in advance.
UPDATE:
Left the phone over night and decided to give it another try. I just tried to fastboot reboot and BEHOLD: the phone rebooted, showed the "cannot check for corruption [..] screen", wiped the data and booted into the stock ROM. I mean: what?!
Futhermore, it shows unlocked under developer settings and:
C:\Users\user>fastboot getvar unlocked
unlocked: yes
Finished. Total time: 0.001s

Although, this is curious to me:
C:\Users\user>fastboot oem device-info
FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed

Perhaps it is just how Sony phones work?
Nonetheless; I do not know what happened - perhaps just reconnected to the PC due to sleep mode? I think it did succeed in unlocking the bootloader after all. Is there any commands I should run before trying to flash the ROM I would like to install?
Thanks again!
